# If $D=P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonalization of $T:V\to V$, why does $P$ contain the eigenvectors of $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

My question is: we say that an operator $T: V\to V$ is diagonalizable if there exists a corresponding diagonal matrix with respect to some basis of $V$. So suppose $A$ is a matrix corresponding to T with respect to another basis. Then we have some matrix $P$ such that the diagonal matrix $D = P^{-1}AP$, where $D$ contains eigenvalues of $T$, and $P$ is the matrix of eigenvectors. So since $P^{-1}AP$ is also known as the change of basis matrix, where $P$ gives the change of basis from one to another, why is that $P$ contains the eigenvectors of $T$?

Comment: "so since $P^{-1}AP$ is also known as the change of basis matrix" -- no. $P$ is called the change of basis matrix. the matrix $P^{-1}AP$ is $D$, the diagonalized matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You have $A=PDP^{-1}$. If we let $P_i$ denote the $i$th column of $P$ and let $e_i$ denote the $i$th standard basis vector, then
$$AP_i=PDP^{-1} P_i = PDe_i = P d_{ii} e_i = d_{ii} P_i,$$
which shows that the $i$th column of $P$ is a $d_{ii}$-eigenvector of $T$.

Comment: so I guess my question would be: how would we compute P^(-1)AP if we didnt know P contained the eigenvectors? How would we specifically compute P just from knowing that it is a matrix involved in change of basis?

Answer (score 0):

Write $PD = AP$, and take $e_i$ to be the vector whose $i$-th coordinate is $1$ and all other coordinates are zero, so that $Pe_i$ is the $i$-th column of $P$. Then $A(Pe_i) = PDe_i = d_i (P e_i)$, where $d_i$ is the $i$-th diagonal entry of $D$. This shows that $P e_i$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $d_i$.

Answer (score 0):

This is because if $A$ is diagonalisable, there exists a *basis of eigenvectors*. Now $P$ is precisely the change of basis matrix from the given basis to the basis of eigenvectors, and the matrix of the operator $T$ in this basis of eigenvectors is given by the change of basis formula:
$$A'=P^{-1}AP.$$
Furthermore, by definition of eigenvectors, the matrix in such basis is a diagonal matrix with the corresponding eigenvalues on the diagonal.

Comment: is P not defined the other way around? Where P takes the a vector in terms of basis of eigenvalue and then maps it to vector in terms of other basis (the basis that A is respective to?)

Comment: Yes $P$ expresses the ‘old’ coordinates in function of the ‘new’ coordinates, and it's precisely for this reason the ‘new’ matrix of $T$ is $P^{-1}AP$.

Comment: so can you tell me what the action of P^(-1)AP is on a vector v? So v must be written in terms of eigenvector basis first? then P sends v to v represented by basis of A. A then takes this vector to another vector still represented by the other basis, and finally p^-1 takes it back to a vector written in terms of eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes. Just make the abstract calculation, denoting with a `'` the new coordinates:  you have  $Y=AX$, $X=PX'$ and $Y=PY'$. So the 1st equality becomes $Y=PY'=A(PX')$, whence $Y'=P^{-1}A(PX')=(P^{-1}AP)X'$.

Comment: So shouldn't your answer say instead "$P$ is precisely the change of basis matrix from the eigenvector basis to the (given) basis of $A$"?

Comment: No. It is indeed as I said, in the conventions I learnt when I was a student. That is probably because from the matrix of $T$ in a given basis, we deduce its matrix  in the new basis.

Comment: Well, the change of basis matrices in both directions are used when transforming one matrix to the other. I guess conventions may differ, but I find the one you were taught to be quite confusing. A very quick google search gave me at least one source that agrees with my convention https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/changebasis/changebasis.pdf. Maybe you could just clarify your convention in your answer.